# Unable to mount any remote filesystem using SSHFS

Tags: sshfs, fuse

So, I was messing with some repositories last week and ran some updates that seem to have broken some things.

I am currently running Mint 17.3 and can no longer mount any remote filesystem using `sshfs`.  This was working before the updates, and `ssh` still works.  Running `sshfs` with just the host and mountpoint, I got

```
fusermount:  failed to access mountpoint [mountpoint]: Permission denied
```

Afterwards, the remote site appeared in the output of `mount`, but appeared in the output of `ls` as

```
d????????? ? ? ? ? [mountpoint]
```

If I tried to access the directory, I was told

```
Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Next, I unmounted the filesystem (even though it was not actually mounted) and then ran the same `sshfs` command using `sudo`.  This time, there was a delay before the command returned a new error:

```
mount:  according to mtab, [site] is already mounted on [mountpoint]
```

The filesystem did not appear in the output of `mount` this time, everything from `ls` looked normal, and I was able to access the (empty) directory I was trying to use as the mountpoint.  I tried adding `-o allow_other` (without `sudo`).

```
fuse:  bad mount point [mountpoint]: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I have tried unmounting the filesystem and killing sshfs processes with no luck.  The issue persists after rebooting as well.  I use sshfs constantly and would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Work checking contents of `/etc/mtab`

Comment: It looks like the parent directory of `[mountpoint]` isn't executable (i.e. openable)?

Comment: Please show us `ls -la /path/to/mountPoint/parent`.  I really want to see its parent's listing.

Comment: @steve, I checked `/etc/mtab`, no sshfs mounts are listed.  
@JuliePelletier, permissions on the parent are `drwxr-xr-x 25 klawson domain users 4096`

Comment: It would have been nice to see the mounting point too (which would have been included in the output I asked you).  What user are you using for the mount?

Comment: @JuliePelletier sorry, there were a lot of other mountpoints in the directory and I was trying to avoid all the clutter.  So, I made a new parent directory and mountpoint, tried again, and have the exact same issue.  Here is the output for the new location: 

`ls -la ~/testparent/

total 12

drwxr-xr-x  3 klawson domain users 4096 Aug  2 15:38 .

drwxr-xr-x 65 klawson domain users 4096 Aug  2 15:37 ..

drwxr-xr-x  2 klawson domain users 4096 Aug  2 15:38 testmount`

I am running `sshfs` as my normal user, klawson, but (as noted above) also have problems when running it using sudo.

Comment: You should try specifying UID and GID like `sshfs -o uid=$UID -o gid=**yourGID** username@server:/path/ mountpoint` as fuse sometimes misleads on the location of the permission issue.

Comment: @JuliePelletier same error :-(